# Finding out the keystrokes given an audio file containing computer keystroke noise

Tags: audio, keyboard

I am looking for a program or web service that can output the keystrokes  given an audio file containing keystroke noise ([example of algorithm](https://www.onthewire.io/recording-keystroke-sounds-over-skype-to-steal-user-data/)).

Any price, license or operating system is fine.

Comment: Franck, I think that only three letter agencies can do that. Even then, might you not have to tune it for individual keyboards, especially older ones? I will mark this as favo(u)rite, though, as I would be interested in such software. Good luck